# Confusion between HTTPS and SSH in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I was learning Git and GitHub and would like to ask some questions on that. I found out that there are two ways to connect and interact with GitHub repo from local PC: via SSH and HTTPS. The confusion I faced is that in here https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-is-the-purpose-of-hypertext-transfer-protocol it says that "The purpose of the HTTP protocol is to provide a standard way for web browsers and servers to talk to each other." Since HTTPS is just more secured version of HTTP, how it is possible that, if we interact with GitHub via HTTPS, we can use shell like bash and not browser to interact with GitHub repo. Secondly, Does HTTPS allow to just transfer data or Does it also allow to manipulate server(creating and deleting files in remote server) like SSH allows us to do?

Comment: There are shell based "browsers" like `curl` and `wget` and `elinks`. Think of `git` as having an invisible, hidden browser built-in to connect to servers like github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The purpose of the HTTP protocol is to provide a standard way for web
>   browsers and servers to talk to each other.

In more general form, HTTP is used to communicate between a client and a server. And the client here can be a web browser or even command-line interface.

> Since HTTPS is just more secured version of HTTP, how it is possible
>   that, if we interact with GitHub via HTTPS, we can use shell like bash
>   and not browser to interact with GitHub repo.

Since it's already established that HTTP/S is for communicating between server and client, and that the web browser is just **one** of the many clients, it's now easy to understand why you can communicate via bash. Do note, that to communicate, authentication is mostly needed and if that is done then you can communicate easy. Here, you are communicating between github server and your commandline, the client.

> Secondly, Does HTTPS allow to just transfer data or Does it also allow
>   to manipulate server(creating and deleting files in remote server)
>   like SSH allows us to do?

It only allows to just transfer data. Remember, HTTPS is just a **protocol**, meaning just a set of rules which, if followed, will **allow** you to transfer **data** between server and clients. Now that **data** is only useful if the server **understands** it.
If, say that **data** contains a command saying **remove all data**, and if the server **understands** and somehow runs the command then yes you manipulated the server in a way.
But in same case if the server doesn't understand then no change occurs. But as you see, thee **HTTPS** has no role in making that change, except to either allow or not allow to transfer that **data**.

Hope this helps in a way.

Edit:
Would also like to add that there are standard HTTP methods, that allow server data modification; POST,DELETE etc. To put this fully, check comments.

Made edits quoting @Z4-tier
"
As mentioned, bash is really not involved with how git communicates with a remote host. Also, the last paragraph is misleading. HTTP absolutely does provide methods that enable manipulation of server resources: DELETE, PUT, POST, etc.... these request methods are part of the specification. I think you are conflating HTTP with the underlying transfer layer protocol. – Z4-tier"

Comment: @Z4-tier Hi thanks for the comment. I'm open for edits !

Comment: As mentioned, bash is really not involved with how git communicates with a remote host. Also, the last paragraph is misleading. HTTP absolutely does provide methods that enable manipulation of server resources: DELETE, PUT, POST, etc.... these request methods are part of the specification. I think you are conflating HTTP with the underlying transfer layer protocol.

Comment: @Z4-tier Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 4):

The choice between HTTPS and SSH for communicating with remote Git repositories usually comes down to a matter of convenience and personal preference. In both cases, Git is simply using an existing and well established protocol to communicate with a remote system. Really. That's all there is to it, no need to overthink. HTTPS is designed for transfering hypertext (thus the name...) but it can be used for other purposes, so don't get stuck thinking that it's limited to your web browser.

If you take a [look at the methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) that are defined for HTTP, you'll see that it provides a powerful set capabilities that facilitate the exchange of arbitrary data. The specification does include methods that can have side effects on the server (DELETE, POST, etc...).

#### How Does Git work Over HTTP ?

To use HTTPS to serve a repository, you need a web server (Apache, Lighthttpd....) configured to use a plugin called [`git-http-backend`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend) as the handler for `git` requests. A couple points to keep in mind:

- `git` is not a web server. It doesn't bind to ports or service HTTP requests directly. It needs a real web server to do that. (*)
- Web servers don't know about `git`. Apache httpd doesn't understand git, becasue that's not it's purpose.

`git-http-backend` is a CGI script that serves as the interface between the web server and the `git` repository on the host system. The web server will bind to the HTTPS port and service incomming connections. When you run `git push` from your local system to a remote host, `git` will connect to the remote server via HTTP. On the server, when  a `git` client connects, that request is forwarded to the CGI plugin for processing.

#### How Does Git Work Over SSH?

It is easier to relate the way we use `git` with `ssh` beacuse they are both tools that we often use at the command line.

When configured to use SSH, `git` does pretty much exactly what you would imagine: it uses the SSH protocol to transfer data and affect changes on the remote repository.

#### Which Is Better?

Sometimes HTTPS is the better option because the necessary ports are usually not blocked by firewalls, whereas SSH sometimes is. I belive GitHub recommends HTTPS for this reason.

HTTP allows for anonymous access to the repository, whereas SSH requires that users have SSH access on the remote server, *even for read-only operations*, like `git pull`.

On the other hand, SSH is usually a lot easier to set up (many Linux distributions have SSH enabled by default) and probably won't require any special configuration to make it work. HTTPS will require some knowledge of how to set up a web server and configure the `git-http-backend` plugin.

The pros and cons of both options are spelled out in much more detail in the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

---

(*) This is not entirely true... Git *does* come with a built in server that uses it's own proprietary protocol (the 'git' protocol), which binds port 9418 and services requests itself. I don't think it is very widely used or even known about. To me, it is an unnecesary feature.